# Append a string to the values in a column

Tags: sql

I want to append a string (text) to a value contained in a column b and insert into column a. 
Column a, value= text1234, Column b, value= 1234. Can this be done.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? The concatenation operators differ. Beyond that, it will be a simple `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: It can be done, but it's probably a bad idea.  What is your motivation?

Comment: But, it may be more appropriate to just calculate it a query time rather than storing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
    a + ', blammy'
... the rest of the query
```

will result in: "text1234, blammy" in some sql databases

You may need to call a function in your sql db.  Here is an examle:

```
select
    concat(a, ', blammy')
.... the rest o the query
```

if the function is named "concat"

**Edit**

Just invert the order as needed

```
'blammy, ' + a
```

or

```
concat('blammy, ', a)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to add blammy to the start of the text e.g blammy_text1234